# not able to get function return value in angularjs http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting undefined for the value returned by the function which is an http request. So I am calling http request inside http.

```
bmgApp.controller('cmpUserSoftwares', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.records = {};
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/company/1'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.records = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.records.length; i++) {
      console.log($scope.records[i]);
      angular.forEach($scope.records[i], function(value, key) {

        if (key == "maincategoryid") {
          value = getSoftwareCategory(value);
        }
        console.log(value + ' : ' + key);
      });
    }
    function getSoftwareCategory(value) {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/software-category/' + value
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var software_category = response.data;
        console.log(software_category);
        return software_category;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error");
      });
    }
    /*angular.forEach($scope.records, function(value, key){
         console.log( $scope.records[key].value + ' : ' + key);
         });*/
    //console.log(response.statusText);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Error");
  });
});
```

The console.log inside getSoftwareCategory function is returning the value but not getting assigned to value variable. I am getting undefined

Comment: getSoftwareCategory works asynchronously, but you are expecting to assign response of getSoftwareCategory(value) to variable value synchronously,
that is the  isssue.

Comment: what is the solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSoftwareCategory` is calling an asynchronous call and from inside and it doesn't actually return anything. (The return value of the inner then() handler is not returned when the parent function is called)

Although this could probably be done better, as a first step, return the promise from `getSoftwareCategory` and do the value assignment using a then() block.

EDIT: New code based on discussion in comments

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/company/1'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    function getSoftwareCategory(record) {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/software-category/' + record.maincategoryid
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            record.maincategoryid = response.data;
            return record;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
    }
    var records = response.data;
    var promises = records.map(function (record) {
        return getSoftwareCategory(record);
    })
    return $q.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        $scope.records = results;
    });
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

Comment: I am getting error on this solution as getSoftwareCategory(...) is undefined

Comment: That's odd. Can you post the exact error message? Also, the brackets were mismatched in the code snippet.. I did my best to guess how to fix it. Perhaps checking that once will help too/

Comment: I fixed that but if i  console.log(value + ' : ' + key); outside if condition it does not display the updated value. What is happening is I am passing software category id called 2 which when in if condition returns the category name from the function but putting it outside if returns it as 2 only.

Comment: Well, it really depends on when you are trying to access the value. Remember that the method you are executing is executing asynchronously... The values will only be available in the `then()` handler. You can then resolve the value using a callback/promise to use it elsewhere. Where exactly are you trying to access the value? Can you update the question to show us how you intend to use that value?

Comment: Edited the answer to update the scope variable. Can you check if it is the behaviour you are expecting?

Comment: $scope.records have values displaying from database and in that I get mainCategoryId value as 2. Since I want to display the category name instead of id in front end. I want to get the category name and assign it to value. I want to re-create new object from this so that i can loop through using ng-repeat.

Comment: I see. Updated my answer. That should work for you with a few tweaks. Good luck

Comment: I solved it by inject $q in the controller. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way I think you are not familier with async programming in JavaScript. The `value` in `value = getSoftwareCategory(value);` will be always `undefined` because your `getSoftwareCategory` is not returning any value. To handle this kind of task in your code you should first read about `promises` in javascript. So your code will be like this after modifying this

```
bmgApp.controller('cmpUserSoftwares', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.records = {};
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/company/1'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    $scope.records = response.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.records.length; i++) {
      console.log($scope.records[i]);
      angular.forEach($scope.records[i], function(value, key) {

        if (key == "maincategoryid") {
          getSoftwareCategory(value).then(software_category => {
            console.log(software_category)
          });
        }
        console.log(value + ' : ' + key);
      });
    }
    function getSoftwareCategory(value) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://megabot/mautonew/wp-json/bmg-comp-listing/v1/software-category/' + value
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        var software_category = response.data;
        console.log(software_category);
        return software_category;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("Error");
      });
    }
    /*angular.forEach($scope.records, function(value, key){
         console.log( $scope.records[key].value + ' : ' + key);
         });*/
    //console.log(response.statusText);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log("Error");
  });
});
```